# Grabbing next line with separate fgets (nested fgets)

Tags: c, fgets

This might be an extremely dumb question (probably), but I'm processing through a text file using fgets. Nothing too fancy:

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), inputFile) != NULL)
```

And that works great, as you would expect. The question I have, then, is that I reach a point where my processing is dependent on the *next* line in the file, but how would I go about grabbing that next line?

The reason I'm finding it tricky is that I still need to process the next line separately when fgets continues looping, but when I'm one line ahead of that line, my function needs to know whether a certain value occurs in the line following it.

Essentially, I don't know if there's a way to almost perform another fgets *within* an fgets, but starting from the current location? I suspect not, but I'm unsure of how else to accomplish it since I don't want to jump to the next line when I'm still trying to process the current line since I sscanf in certain input values and I don't want to overwrite them.

If that made no sense, I'll try to clarify it, but any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Just an idea: store line 1 in some kind of a buffer, then read line 2, if line 2 contains something that should trigger an action with data from line 1, you can access it with that buffer

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking. May give that a shot.

Comment: Good luck, if you solve it you could let us know by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use circular queue of capacity two. Init the queue with two lines. Pseudo code might look like this.

```
CircularQueue cq = CircularQueue(first_line, second_line);
while(true) {
   if (check(cq[SECOND_ELEMENT])) {
       process(cq[FIRST_ELEMENT]);
       remove(cq[FIRST_ELEMENT])
       append(cq, fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), inputFile))
   } else {
       break;
   }
}
```

Ofcourse, because we already know we want to process two elements as at a time, we could just maintain pointer as previous_element & current_element. previous_element will point to second last line you have read and current_element will point to last line you have read.

Comment: Because you don't want to read the next line if you're already on the last line, maybe it's better to work with `previous_element` `current_element` instead?

Comment: @TimCastelijns agree. I will modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getdata(char **buf, char **nextBuf, int bufsize, FILE *inFile )
{
   char *ret;
   static char *cBuf = NULL;
   static char *nBuf = NULL;
   static char *nRet = NULL;
   static int bSize = 0;

   if( cBuf ==NULL && nBuf==NULL && bufsize !=0 ) {
      if( bufsize != 0 ) {
         // allocate buffers and init them with first two lines of load.
         bSize = bufsize;
         cBuf = malloc( bSize );
         nBuf = malloc( bSize );
         if ( cBuf && nBuf ) {
            if( (ret = fgets(cBuf, bSize, inFile)) != NULL ) {   
               *buf = cBuf;
               // get next line ahead of time the first time we are called.
               nRet = fgets(nBuf, bSize, inFile);
               *nextBuf = (nRet==NULL)? NULL : nBuf;          
            }
         }
      }
      else {
        ret = NULL;
      }
   }
   else if( cBuf==NULL && nBuf==NULL && bufsize == 0 ) {
      // shutdown, cleanup
      free( cBuf ); cBuf = NULL;
      free( nBuf ); nBuf = NULL;
      bSize = 0;
      *buf = NULL;
      *nextBuf = NULL;
      ret = nRet = NULL;
   }
   else {
      // set current line to the previously fetched next line
      if( nRet ) {
         char *tmp;
         // swap buffers
         tmp = cBuf; 
         cBuf = nBuf;
         nBuf = tmp;
         *buf = cBuf;
         ret = nRet;
         // now get the NEW next line
         nRet = fgets(nBuf, bSize, inFile);
         *nextBuf = (nRet==NULL)? NULL : nBuf;          
      }
      else {
        ret = nRet;
      }
   }
   return ret;
}


int main(void)
{
   char *buf = NULL;
   char *nbuf = NULL;
   while( getdata( &buf, &nbuf, 2048, stdin ) != NULL ) {
       // process line.  if needed, next line, if available is in nbuf 
       // (nbuf can be ptr to NULL if next line not present, be careful.)
       printf( "%s", buf );
   }
   getdata( NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);
}
```